# How to use coupon and wallet in woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, coupon, wallet

I need help as well as suggestions, my point is, I have to give Rs.2000 to first time logged in users,and every-time user use coupon and only 5% of the total will deduct from Rs.2000 and rest of the amount, user can use later, but only 5% will deduct every-time. How I'm manage this type of functionality in woo-commerce? Or is there any plugin to manage this.

Comment: Basically, how to use coupon in wallet?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it will help

https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/coupon-generator-for-woocommerce/

or for example

https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/smart-coupons/

Comment: Basically, how to use coupon in wallet amount?

Comment: or you can say, wallet amount redeem only 5%, everytime.

Comment: @MaceLong I do not know such details. I advise you to test.